# Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on float LARAVEL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

My objective is to get average review of the courses available. But when i am trying to get the average review of the course its throwing me an error saying `"message": "Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on float"`

My Course Model

```
 public function rating(){
    return $this->hasMany(Rating::class);
}
public function averageRating(){
    return round($this->rating()->avg('ratings'),1);
}
```

Rating model

```
 public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    public function course(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Course::class);
    }
```

My Controller

```
$result = Course::with('averageRating')->get();
```

I was expecting it to give Course detail along with average rating of each course but it throwing error.
Can anyone please help me?? 
Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AverageRating method isn't a relation and you can't use it such as relation.
If you want have average rating , set averageRating to appended attributes.

Course.php:

```
protected $appends = [
    'average-rating'
];

function getAverageRatingAttribute(){
    return round($this->rating()->avg('ratings'),1);
}
```

Comment: I made the changes as you recommended  and then i called the `getAverageRatingAttribute` method from the controller.But still the same error

Comment: No you don't need call getAverageRatingAttribue method . laravel call it and create a average-rating attribute and you can access to it on each row. for example course1->average-rating.

Answer (score 0):

The `with` is used to eager load realtions and hence **Laravel expects an eloquent model to be returned when trying to eager load**. But you are passing a float value (using `round()`).

A solution is to simply eager load:

```
$result = Course::with('rating')->get();
```

and then access average rating by doing:

```
foreach($result as $r){
    echo $r->averageRating;
}
```

Comment: This is give the dump the rating .....and after that if i loop for average rating it will return the same.  
Apart from that passing the data to the view will be difficult and query will be long