# Laravel call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on float

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get sum of columns in relationship model but i get this error

> Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on float

## Code

`model`

```
public function cableLentgh()
{
    return $this->links()->sum('cable_length');
}
```

## Logic

1. my model has relationship to `link` model like this

> ```
> public function links()
> {
>     return $this->hasManyThrough(Link::class, Segment::class, 'hthree_id', 'segment_id');
> }
> ```

2. in `links` table I have column named `cable_length` where numbers are stored
3. now I want to have SUM of those numbers.

**Any idea?**

## Update

full error detail

```
exception: "Error"
file: "C:\laragon\www\web\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php"
line: 578
message: "Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on float"
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug this? Can you share the full and exact error message, which should at least contain the file and line throwing that error, if not also the stacktrace

Comment: plz post the code that u use cableLength.

Comment: I think the problem is you are using some code like `with('cableLentgh'`

Comment: @TsaiKoga yes in my controller i am trying to get this model function in `with()` that's why in first place i added this function to my model

Comment: @mafortis my answer may help u here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59897448/call-to-a-member-function-addeagerconstraints-on-string/59897724#59897724

Comment: @TsaiKoga sorry your sample code is using morphable table mine is `hasManyThrough` how should i change it?

Comment: I think the problem is `with` need the relationship. however, `cableLentgh()` return a float. and the error occurs. So if you want to use `with()`, the cableLentgh() need to return relationship. not just a number.

Comment: @TsaiKoga in that case i already have my links relationship returning then having `cableLentgh()` would be useless i guess. Well that way i think best way would be doing `sum` in front-end based on `links()` relation

Answer (score 0):

If you relationship is correct then you should get the `collection` of links by the following call:

`$this->link`;

If it returns the collections, you can then run `sum` method of collection as below:

```
public function cableLentgh()
{
    return $this->links->sum('cable_length'); //Notice () removed
}
```

I know this might not be the exact answer for your problem as you are trying to get the `sum` by query which is better option. As it's not working, then using `collection` is also an option that may solve your problem.

Comment: thanks but it returns `Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on int`

Comment: In that case you should be confirm that the relationship is not working correctly. have you tried to see what the return of `$this->link`?

Answer (score 0):

For me you should use the variable, and not the function `link` :

```
public function cableLentgh()
{
    return $this->links->sum('cable_length');
}
```

Comment: it returns `Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on int`

Comment: Ok, but `$this->links` should return a collection, be sure of your relations, and test links to understand what is returned

Comment: if i use `$this->links()` it return correct data. if `$this->link` it return error `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::addEagerConstraints does not exist.`

Comment: as of error seems this is what it's mean https://stackoverflow.com/a/48129928/8490993

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with the relationship ids',I would try to specify like in hasManyThrough documentation

```
class Country extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Post',
            'App\User',
            'country_id', // Foreign key on users table...
            'user_id', // Foreign key on posts table...
            'id', // Local key on countries table...
            'id' // Local key on users table...
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: didn't make any changes

Comment: check if this thread helps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48108935/call-to-a-member-function-addeagerconstraints-on-float-laravel

Comment: when i use attribute it says `Call to undefined relationship [cableLentgh] on model [App\ZoneRegion].`